# Статус слова «многолюднело»

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, словообразование, значение-слов, окказионализмы

*Ближе к обеду в ресторане «Веранда» значительно **многолюднело.***
[А. Князева. Прощальный поцелуй Греты Гарбо](https://books.google.ee/books?id=NDpEDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT226&lpg=PT226&dq=%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=lOFpyelYOW&sig=ACfU3U1MwkPIrGIZ7xdeSiK04b8T34cOnQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjczane3_TgAhVNposKHQoqCyoQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE&f=false)

Я не встречалась с этим словом ранее, и оно меня, честно говоря, удивило.
Как вы считаете — имеет ли слово *многолюднело* "право на жизнь"?
К какой части речи оно относится и чем является в предложении?
По какому принципу образовано?

Comment: по почему собственно не ***многолюДЕло*** по аналогии с ***обезлюдеть***?

Comment: Я читала [печатную] книгу. Попалось вот такое словцо. Оно меня "клюнуло". И я никак не могу знать — _почему собственно  не многолюДЕло…_

Comment: вопрос не к вам персонально, он риторический

Comment: Дело в том, что глагола **многолюдеть** нет.

Comment: в том-то и вопрос, почему его нет, а ***обезлюдеть*** есть, корень-то один, ну и глагола ***многолюдНеть*** также "не было", пока он вам не встретился, и зачем ему суффикс -Н-?

Answer (score 2):

Само по себе слово возможно как окказионализм. Значение, которое можно определить из конструкции слова (ср.: *смеркалось*): "**становилось многолюдно**" (об обеденных часах вообще). Не уверен, что уместно сочетать с этим словом эпитет "значительно".

Comment: органично сочетается с совершенной формой - **значительно помноголюд(н)ело**

Comment: @Alex_ander _1. Само по себе слово возможно как окказионализм._ Совершенно верно, такую метку я и поставила в вопросе. 2. _Значение, которое можно определить из конструкции слова (ср.: смеркалось)..._ Простите, но я ничего не поняла. 3. _Значительно_ — это эпитет?